# Remove multiple values from array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, unset

I have the following array:

```
array(5) { 
    ["destino"]=> string(11) "op_list_gen" 
    ["id_terminal"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["marca"]=> string(2) "--" 
    ["tipo"]=> string(2) "--" 
    ["lyr_content"]=> string(14) "aawaw"
}
```

How can I remove the values **"--"** and **empty** values from the array?

I have tried using a foreach and removing the elements found with unset but it´s not working.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $arra) {
        if(array_key_exists('--', $array)){ 
            unset($arra[$key]);
        }
}
```

Comment: look into http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php with a custom callback

Comment: The key is not "--" the value is "--" thus array_key_exist will always be false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to solve this:

```
$arr = [
    "destino" => "op_list_gen",
    "id_terminal" => "",
    "marca" => "--",
    "tipo" => "--",
    "lyr_content" => "aawaw"
];

$newArr = array_filter($arr, function($value) {
    return !in_array($value, ['', '--']);
});
```

> **demo:** https://ideone.com/oot7lZ

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = [
    "destino" => "op_list_gen",
    "id_terminal" => "",
    "marca" => "--",
    "tipo" => "--",
    "lyr_content" => "aawaw"
];

$new_array = array_filter($array, function($item){
    if($item != '--' || $item != '')
        return $item;
})

var_dump($new_array)
```

`array_filter()` will take each entry and return it if it's not `--` or `''`

Comment: The callback in `array_filter()` normally returns true/false to either keep or remove the item.

Answer (score 1):

Generic approach should look like that:

```
$filter = function(...$excluded) {
     return function ($value) use ($excluded) {
        return !in_array($value, $excluded);
  };
};

$newArray = array_filter($array, $filter('', '--'));
```

This approach is reusable, because you don't need to hardcode values right insight your filtering function.

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$original = [
    'destino' => 'op_list_get',
    'id_terminal' => '',
    'marca' => '--',
    'tipo' => '--',
    'lyr_content' => 'aawaw',
];

// values you want to filter away
$disallowArray = ['', '--'];
$filteredResult = array_filter($original, function($val) use($disallowArray) {
    // check that the value is not in our disallowArray
    return \in_array($val, $disallowArray, true) === false;
});
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [destino] => op_list_get
    [lyr_content] => aawaw
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove values by simply looping over the array, creating a new array in the process:

```
$myarray = array( 
  "destino" => "op_list_gen",
  "id_terminal" => "",
  "marca" => "--", 
  "tipo" => "--", 
  "lyr_content" => "aawaw",
}

$newarray = array();
foreach($myarray as $key => $value) {
    if($value != "--" && $value != "") {
        $newarray[$key] = $value;
  }
}
```

Or, more elegantly, you could use the `array_filter` function. It takes a callback function that, for each value, decides whether to include it. This also returns a new array:

```
$newarray = array_filter($myarray, function($elem) {
    if($elem != "" && $elem != "--") return $elem;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As all the other answers say, [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) is a good way to go about that. However, this is returning a new array and doesn't actually modify the original array. If that's what you're looking for, this might be a different approach:

```
// Start infinite loop
while(true){
    // Check for value in array
    if (($key = array_search('--', $arr)) !== false || ($key = array_search('', $arr)) !== false) {
        // Unset the key
        unset($arr[$key]);
        // Reset array keys
        $arr = array_values($arr);
    } else {
        // No more matches found, break the loop
        break;
    }
}
```